# JAX-RS and Spring inside JSF webapplication running under tomcat, how to configurate?

Tags: spring, rest, jsf, jax-rs

Is this class necessary when you want to implement a webservice using jax-rs in JSF application handled by Spring ? (RequestContextFilter.class)

I don't understand what it is really doing.

```
   @ApplicationPath("/API")
   public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    register(JacksonFeature.class); /* Use to get Json ok */ 
    register(GraphicService.class);/* my webservice ok */

    /* 
    register(RequestContextFilter.class); bridge between JAX-RS and Spring, and so 
    */
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried *not* using it? What happens?

Comment: Nothing happens, but i get a memory leak (OutOfMemomry : PermGenSpace)on the webservice(whith and without RequestContextFilter) and i was wondering if it could be caused by unregistering this class. And then i was just curious to know about the utility of this class...